# Javascript: What's the purpose of .prototype.constructor?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Being a beginner in JavaScript, I wonder what is the purpose of `.prototype.constructor`?  What is the purpose of

```
Function Foo(a) {
  this.a = a,
  this.b = b
}
```

What exactly is a ***constructor function***? Thank you.

Comment: Every object in js contains the ```constructor``` property, which is just a reference to the function used to create this object. In practice you will rarely use, unless you try to invoke it dynamically or doing any reflection related tasks